# Feature extraction for Timeseries LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, feature-extraction

I want to feed a timeseries into an LSTM to perform a forecast.
Lets say I have 10000 samples. Now in order to feed the timeseries into my LSTM I reshape it to (samples,timesteps,features). In my case I use timesteps=50 to create subsequences and perform a forecast of t+1. So I end up with `x.shape=(9950,50,1)`. So far so good.

My Model

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(50,1)))
model.add(Dense(out_dim, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

NOW I want to create artificial features e.g. I want to use the fft of the signal as a feature. How I can feed it into my LSTM? Is it legitimate to just compute the fft, append it to the Dataframe and reshape all together so I end up with `(9950,50,2)`??

Questions are basically:

1. How I input artifical created features into an LSTM?
2. Its the same way for rolling statistics or correlation features?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any extra feature you compute from the input data is just another feature so:

1. You feed it just like another feature of series, `input_shape=(50, 1+extra_features)` and you will have to concatenate those prior to passing to model. So yes, the input shape will now be `(9950, 50, 2)`.
2. Yes it is, you can pre-compute that feature let's say moving average and then concatenate it with the original input.

You can also write custom layers to compute these features within the model, but the model would have compute it every time. If you compute it a priori, the advantage is you can save / cache it.

If you have non-timeseries features, now you need to move onto the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) and have multiple inputs: 1 which is timeseries and another which is not:

```
series_in = Input(shape=(50, 2))
other_in = Input(shape(extra_features,)) # not a timeseries just a vector
# An example graph
lstm_out = LSTM(128)(series_in)
merged = concatenate([lstm_out, other_in])
out = Dense(out_dim, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model = Model([series_in, other_in], out)
model.compile(...)
```

In this case we have 2 inputs to the model and can use the auxiliary features at any point. In the example, I merge before the final Dense layer to aid the predication along with the timeseries features extracted with the LSTM.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! You also know how I go about features which are not a timeseries? E.g. number of peaks or any numerical value which is important to characterize my signal? To be concrete lety say I have two peaks in my signal, how can I feed this value to the model?

Comment: Right, I was thinking about adding that info to the answer, I'll update in a second.

Comment: Ok I can compile it like this, but does it make sense when I just add the numbers to the output of the LSTM-Layer? In my understanding I get an encoded Vector fom my LSTM layer and then I merge it with some features, but the relation from my extra features to my encoded vector is unclear? So why does this work? It compiles but why does it make sense? Anyway thanks alot!

Comment: It's all just features for the Dense layer, it will adjust the bias / weights to find useful patterns. So if the LSTM outputs some feature vector and you have 2 spikes might be a condition the Dense layer learns. This is just one way, you might want to add another `latent = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(other_in)` and then merge `latent`. This will add some feature extraction from the extra features you've given.

Comment: @nuric Thanks a lot for your great answer. I am following the model you have used for my dataset and I have to do a presentation on this. Since, I cannot have the code in the presentation, do you know how we can draw these layers as a diagram?

Comment: Colah has nice diagrams: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/